# Android layout_weight iframe and scroll

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-layout-weight

sorry for my poor english in advance
I have a design problem on android studio.
I used multiples devices (From version 8 to 10) and it works fine, and one device (version 6) which has a different output (you can check my screens below)[wrong display click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtJt7.png)
[good display click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a2mo.jpg)
unfortunately i don't know why it goes wrong, it might be a problem with layout_weight, in my code i use a Frame layout to switch out between differents Views, it looks like the Framelayout doesn't take any height (i want it to take the available space)
Thanks in advance

> 

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/choose_model"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/select_your_model"
            android:layout_width="43dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/text_model_title"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_model_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/choose_mod"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Spinner_model_preference_text"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/select_your_model"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FAFAFA">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/Frame_layout_preferences_setting"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save_user_preferences"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/save" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_preferences_model"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/recycler_view_preferences_model"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
    </RelativeLayout></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the wrong with your picture?

Comment: there is nothing displayed (ahead of the save button you should see the content of the good picture)

Comment: you xml  is contened in activity or fragment

Comment: it's contained in a fragment

Answer (score 0):

You have the problem, because you have a FrameLayout inside a fragment. I recommend the next

If you only want to have a view  and it has different content, you can have a activity

> ```
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_weight="0">
>
>     <Spinner
>         android:id="@+id/select_your_model"
>         android:layout_width="43dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/text_model_title"
>         android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/text_model_title"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
>         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>         android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
>         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
>         android:text="@string/choose_mod"
>         android:textSize="20sp"
>         android:textStyle="bold" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/Spinner_model_preference_text"
>         android:layout_width="160dp"
>         android:layout_height="26dp"
>         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/select_your_model"
>         android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
>         android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
>         android:textSize="16sp"
>         android:textStyle="bold" />
> </RelativeLayout>
>
> <ScrollView
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="0dp"
>     android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
>     android:layout_weight="1"
>     android:background="#FAFAFA">
>
>     <FrameLayout
>         android:id="@+id/Frame_layout_preferences_setting"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
> </ScrollView>
>
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
>     android:layout_weight="0">
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/save_user_preferences"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="40dp"
>         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         android:text="@string/save" />
> </RelativeLayout>
>
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="0dp"
>     android:layout_weight="0.2">
>
>     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
>         android:id="@+id/recycler_view_preferences_model"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
>
>     <View
>         android:id="@+id/divider2"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="1dp"
>         android:layout_above="@+id/recycler_view_preferences_model"
>         android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
>         android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
> </RelativeLayout></LinearLayout>
> ```

Replace the FrameLayout with an imageview

if you want  to have fragments.  i recommend the next

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Call the fragment in activity

> ```
> getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
>                     .replace(R.id.main_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
> ```

Comment: i'll try to use an activity then, but i don't understand the problem of using fragment, i'm just adding views dynamically into my FrameLayout

Comment: Because you have a FrameLayout  inside a fragmen, it is not correct, because the fragment must be inside an activity